# Math/Physics: Given angle and vector find point of intersection?

Tags: vector, collision-detection, intersection, angle

I have two objects and I need to determine whether they will collide at some time in the future. Say the two objects are trucks, each in their separate lane. The first truck wants to change lanes, but will the trucks collide?

Both objects are **moving forward**, but only the first has an angle. The objects are **moving at different, varying velocities**, yet only the velocity of the second object is known. Also, the two objects are operating on **separate coordinate systems** (meaning each object has a new origin), with varying distance between the objects.

I don't have a vector for the first object, but I do have an angle (not fixed) at which it is headed, relative to the x-axis.

For the second object, I have a vector, and it is headed straight.

Please refer to the picture below:

[image: Collision]

How can I find the point of intersection, based on these criteria? I imagine the angle is an infinite line, which at some point will cross the vector magnitude of the second object. I don't suppose this is as straight forward as calculating the point of intersection of two lines.

Wrapup:

- Velocity of the second object is known (but varying)
- Angle of the first object is known
- Distance between the objects is known (but varying)
- Acceleration in the x-direction of the first object is known (But I **CANNOT** use this to find the velocity due to limitations)

Comment: Because you don't know the velocities of the objects, you can't guarantee that they'll collide.  You could approximate where they *potentially* collide, but again, without velocities, you'll have no certainties.

Comment: Do you at least know the position of the objects relative to each other?

Comment: I forgot to mention that. I have the distance between the two objects.

Comment: Distance *and* angle, or just distance?  Could you possibly give us a bit of context for your question?  Right now it seems rather abstract.

Comment: I realize that. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have redrawn your image with a few more labels on it.

[image]

First we need to be working in one coordinate system. I have chosen to use the system with object 1 at (0,0). This means that object 2 is at position (Xd,Yd).

Then we find the point of intersection. In these coordinates this point will be x=0 and y=y1 (0,y1). Now we want to know what this is in terms of y2, yd and the angle theta.

[image: eq1]

Using what you know this now tells us where the intersection point is. We need to find out how long it takes each object to get to that point. Taking this time for each and setting them equal to each other will give us the conditions on the velocity and acceleration of each object that will make them collide. Starting with the constant acceleration equation for object 1 and 2 (find these in any intro physics book):

[image: ca1]

[image: ca2]

where **y0** is the starting position, **V0** is the initial velocity, and **a** is the acceleration.

**y0** for object 1 will be 0 since we called that the origin and **y0** for object 2 will just be **yd**.

Now solve for **t** in each of these and set them equal to each other. Since these are just quadratic in **t** we can use the quadratic equation. After this you should get:

[image: full]

with,

[image: with]

Then plug in the values you know for velocities, accelerations and positions. If both sides are equal they collide, if not, they dont. This essentially sets conditions on these quantities that have to be met in order for them to be at the same place, at the same time, i.e. a collision.

Comment: You are absolutely right and my question should have been more clear. But suppose I have the velocity of the second object, would that help?

Comment: You really need the velocity of both objects. If you have it for both then you know where on the line the object travels it will be at any time T. You can then just find what time each of the objects will be at the intersection point and if the times are equal (or very close depending on the size of the objects) then they will collide. To be more concrete: object 1 will be a distance x1 along its line at time T1 = x1 / v1 (and similar for object 2). Then if T1 = T2 they will collide. You could also convert each objects distance along the line into its coordinates.

Comment: Sorry I should have said: to solve the problem you should set x1 and x2 to the distances along the line that correspond to the intersection point.

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully this will help. Otherwise, I will need to reask this question when I collect some more information.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Its maybe not as simple as you hoped but its an algorithmic way to check with some known information, whether a colision will happen or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this solution assumes constant acceleration, which is not necessarily the case. I will need to find a workaround, but for the given information in this question, your answer will suffice.

Comment: This is true that constant acceleration is assumed, however if acceleration is not constant you are getting into a whole new ball game. You basically will be forced to use calculus at that point and if you are doing this in some program that means doing some numerical integration. Its still doable but will be **much** more difficult.

Comment: could you please clarify this: *Then we find the point of intersection. In these coordinates this point will be x=0 and y=y1 (0,y1).* Why is it (0, y1) instead of (x2, y2)? From the drawing it looks exactly (x2, y2)

Comment: Sorry its been a long time since I posted this. This is because the object on the right is the '1' object and its where I have defined the coordinates from. Since it is only moving in the vertical direction, its ending position is still at x=0. I should have placed the X-Y axis marker in a better spot.